# Stitch mapbox tiles

Tags: tiles, printing, mapbox

I have customized mapbox tiles and i need to print it on  A2 size paper on high zoom level at around scale of 500 to 1000. I am thinking of  stitching  the adjacent tiles together to form a single big map. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

With Linux you can use QBigMap:
http://ruessel.in-chemnitz.de/osm/qbigmap/

A Perl-Script can be found in the OSM-Wiki:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bigmap

Answer (score 1):

The Modest Maps compose.py script is made for this: https://github.com/migurski/modestmaps-py

Answer (score 0):

Change the location of tile server in https://github.com/maxolasersquad/osm_download

Answer (score 0):

Layout the map in actual size(if its a large map), save it as .pdf then use adobe pdf reader to print using its "poster" feature you can print large image/map in regular size paper, it will automatically divide into desired size of paper. that will do as work around solution. hope it help=)